# Please explain syntax

Tags: perl, syntax

I'm looking for help explaining the following syntax. I have checked my Perl book, and checked around online.

I'm looking for the following:

```
$option =~ s/\s+//g
$option =~ m/^\s*$
```

Many thanks.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Answer (score 5):

`s` and `m` are operators that apply [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to a string. [`s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html) is the substitution operator and [`m//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) is the match operator. They both take a regular expression as their first arguement (inside the `//`). The `=~` tells Perl to use/match the regex against `$option`. See [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more info on that.

Here's what these regex do:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new( qr/\s+/ )->explain;

The regular expression:

(?-imsx:\s+)
matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In short: it replaces every instance of whitespace-characters that has more than one of them with nothing.

And:

```
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new( qr/^\s*$/ )->explain;
```

The regular expression:

```
(?-imsx:^\s*$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And that one matches if the string contains only whitespace characters. As many as possible, but at least zero of them, and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce., You guys have been very helpfull as usuall. Thanks very much.

Comment: "These are regular expressions." Actually `s///` and `m//` are both operators. It's their first arguments that are regular expressions. It's a subtle distinction - but important.

Comment: You are correct of course. I'll edit the answer to reflect that. Thanks Dave.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the first expression is a `s`(ubstitution) that looks for one or more whitespaces and eliminates them.  the `+` specifies one or more whitespace (`\s`) characters.

The second looks to `m`(atch) an empty line.  The `^` anchors tje match to the beginning of the line and the `$` to the end.  Hence only lines that contain zero or more (i.e. `*`) whitespaces are successfully matched.

Both expressions operate against the `$option` variable since the `=~` binds them to it.